# limit of an rational-exponential expression

Tags: limits

I am looking for the derivation of the following limit

$$\lim\limits_{w \to -1^{+}}  \frac{-\sqrt{2 w {{e}^{w+1}}+2}+w+1}{w e^w+{{e}^{-1}}}$$
the value given by Mathematica is $-\frac{2 e}{3}$.
(now corrected)
I have tried using L'Hopital's rule but the expressions become more complicated.

Comment: Are you sure that the limit is correct? Because for $w\rightarrow-1^+$ the denominator becames $-1+e^{-1}$, while the numerator becames 0

Comment: So, as written, the limit is $0$. No need for L'Hopital's rule.